# Android - umano SlidingUpPanelLayout - content fitsSystemWindows

Tags: android, slidingpanelayout

I am using the following library : https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel.

I want to display things below status bar when scrolling and I can't make the main_content (first container of the SlidingUpPanelLayout) fit the screen. I want to display things below status bar when scrolling.

This is my first xml configuration :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    ...
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <com.hnhh.app3.fragments.model.FitsSystemWindowsFrameLayout
        ...
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <!-- This is where I don't get what I want,
             This container has always a padding top equals to the 
             status bar size, so it will always affect the direct 
             childs => main_content (my fragments container) -->
        <com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
            android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true" // seems to not be supported
            android:gravity="bottom"
            ...>

            <!-- Main content - fragments placeholder -->
            <com.hnhh.app3.fragments.model.FitsSystemWindowsFrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true" // if the parent doesn't it will not either.
                tools:background="@color/colorAccent" />

            <!-- Panel     -->
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/..."
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="false" />
        </com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom">

            <com.hnhh.app3.widgets.BannerAdWrapper.../>
        </FrameLayout>

    </com.hnhh.app3.fragments.model.FitsSystemWindowsFrameLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/navigation" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I tried with several parent's for the sliding_layout but I can't manage to have the desired behavior. The sliding_layout never fits the screen.

Another way I tried, which kinda works, is to replace main_content with an empty ViewGroup which has to match_paren (the library wants it that way) and the main_content not inside the SlidingUpPanelLayout but before.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout >
    <com.hnhh.app3.fragments.model.FitsSystemWindowsFrameLayout>

        <!-- NEW Main content - fragments placeholder -->
        <com.hnhh.app3.fragments.model.FitsSystemWindowsFrameLayout />

        <com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
            <!--  Replaced old main_content with empty     -->
            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

            <!--  Panel     -->
            <FrameLayout />
        </com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>

        <FrameLayout>
            <com.hnhh.app3.widgets.BannerAdWrapper/>
        </FrameLayout>

    </com.hnhh.app3.fragments.model.FitsSystemWindowsFrameLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/navigation" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The thing with the second solution is that I have an empty container that will intercept all touch events and I couldn't manage to pass them to the main content.

Does anyone got a workaround? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found a way through.

I removed the library and used a custom BottomSheetBehavior like in https://github.com/fedorenkoalex/bottomsheetrecycler/. Follow the link and look how it was implemented. Thanks to *fedorenkoalex* for the solution.

The results are almost the same, the only thing is when you scroll the nested recycler view (or other scroll view) it will handle scrolls well except when you cannot scroll up anymore : if the RecyclerView is already at the top and you try to scroll top, then it will push the bottom sheet down. Which is not bad in the end because it's an intuitive behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this xml Layout:

```
<!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.amitupadhyay.clickin.in.amitupadhyay.clickin.ui.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MY_TAB_STYLE">
        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/viewPager">

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</LinearLayout>


<!-- SLIDING LAYOUT -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:id="@+id/dragView">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:id="@+id/bottomPannerLinearLayout"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/follow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/anyid"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>


            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="55dp"
                android:id="@+id/anyotherid"
                style="@style/AppTheme.Button"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:text="Submit"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This works great for me. :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I replicated your code inside a SlidingUpPanelLayout but I still get a padding top for the SlidingUpPanelLayout which is the status bar height. I tried to play with several variables like *windowTranslucentStatus*, *windowActionBarOverlay*, *windowContentOverlay* but still. I may be wrong somewhere.